# Custom ListView in a fragment, what files do I need?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, baseadapter

I already created this with custom adapter in another project, but I didn't use fragments. I now have a project using fragments, and am displaying the listview in a fragment. I don't know or am able to find exactly what **rules** and what **classes/java files** I need for this to work in a fragment.

Every example on the internet I've used develops an error in some way, and since I don't understand every aspect of how this is done I can't fix it on my own.

In my previous project, I did this (CalculationsActivity.java):

```
public class CalculationsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {
 //content of my class
}

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayLi.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.calcer);
    String[] convertedArrLi = arrayLi.toArray(new String[arrayLi.size()]);
    String[] convertedDates = dates.toArray(new String[dates.size()]);

    content.setText(convertedArrLi[i]);
    date.setText(convertedDates[i]);

    return view;
 }
}
```

And from that I set an adapter to my listview. This class was in the same java file as the activity that the listview was displayed in. If I do this in my fragment, I get a bunch of red lines. getLayoutInflater() and variables from my other class above it will be red.

As I understand so far you need MainActivity.java, MyFragment.java and Adapter.java. To make your listview work with your array you need to set an adapter including the current activity and the array you want to use. If someone can explain what files I actually need and how they work together (send info to each other and start one another), I would appreciate it.

Note: I have to use a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom adapter in activity and in fragment, there is no difference. Can you provide screenshot of your bunch of red lines?

Also your question is incorrect: "what files do I need?". You need classes, first class for activity or fragment to create/declare/initialize second class (custom adapter) and fill it with data.